# App SIGABRT Crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, sigabrt

When I run my iOS app in Xcode & test it on my device (before submitting) it returns no errors and it works flawlessly. But when I test the app after the update to the app store, it crashes every time I open the app on my device. I get the following error in my crash log:

```
Exception Type: EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread: 0
Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x2f9ecf06 __exceptionPreprocess + 126
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3a183ce2 objc_exception_throw + 34
2   CoreData                        0x2f72a694 -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator initWithManagedObjectModel:] + 392
3   TapNotes                        0x00015d3c -[AppDelegate persistentStoreCoordinator] (AppDelegate.m:104)
4   TapNotes                        0x00015b48 -[AppDelegate managedObjectContext] (AppDelegate.m:73)
5   TapNotes                        0x00016904 -[DeviceViewController managedObjectContext] (HomeViewController.m:22)
6   TapNotes                        0x00016b04 -[DeviceViewController viewDidAppear:] (HomeViewController.m:51)
7   UIKit                           0x32236d1e -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 434
8   UIKit                           0x322e6052 -[UINavigationController viewDidAppear:] + 178
9   UIKit                           0x32236d1e -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 434
10  UIKit                           0x3229be7a -[UIViewController _executeAfterAppearanceBlock] + 50
11  UIKit                           0x3229be04 _applyBlockToCFArrayCopiedToStack + 312
12  UIKit                           0x32214b6e _afterCACommitHandler + 454
13  CoreFoundation                  0x2f9b8034 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 16
14  CoreFoundation                  0x2f9b59c2 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 282
15  CoreFoundation                  0x2f9b5d0e __CFRunLoopRun + 734
16  CoreFoundation                  0x2f920764 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520
17  CoreFoundation                  0x2f920546 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
18  GraphicsServices                0x3488d6ce GSEventRunModal + 134
19  UIKit                           0x3227f88c UIApplicationMain + 1132
20  TapNotes                        0x00016886 main (main.m:16)
21  libdyld.dylib                   0x3a681ab2 tlv_initializer + 2


Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a7381f0 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a7a07b2 pthread_kill + 54
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a6e8ff4 abort + 72
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x39b3798a abort_message + 70
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x39b506e2 default_terminate_handler() + 250
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3a183f7a _objc_terminate() + 190
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x39b4e1b0 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 76
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x39b4dd12 __cxa_rethrow + 98
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3a183e2a objc_exception_rethrow + 38
9   CoreFoundation                  0x2f9207da CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 638
10  CoreFoundation                  0x2f920546 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
11  GraphicsServices                0x3488d6ce GSEventRunModal + 134
12  UIKit                           0x3227f88c UIApplicationMain + 1132
13  TapNotes                        0x00016886 main (main.m:16)
14  libdyld.dylib                   0x3a681ab4 start + 0

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a725804 kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3a674050 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 228
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3a66e2de _dispatch_mgr_thread + 34

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a738c70 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a79dc1e _pthread_wqthread + 306
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a79dad8 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a738c70 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a79dc1e _pthread_wqthread + 306
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a79dad8 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x00002060
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x3c69418c      r6: 0x00000000      r7: 0x27df2594
    r8: 0x17e8d090    r9: 0x00000001     r10: 0x0000000c     r11: 0x00000002
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x27df2588      lr: 0x3a7a07b7      pc: 0x3a7381f0
  cpsr: 0x00000010
```

I have tried opening on multiple devices & the same thing occurs. What should I do to resvole this issue?

Comment: Look at the crash log on your device and see where your app crashes.

Comment: Based on what you have posted, it is impossible to tell. What does *testing before submitting* mean in your case? Ad-Hoc builds, running a quick build while plugged into XCode?

Comment: @rmaddy where does it say on the crash log? It just has lots of weird letters and numbers all jumbled.

Comment: Here is a good start: http://www.raywenderlich.com/23704/demystifying-ios-application-crash-logs

Comment: You have to symbolicate the crash log. You did an archive build in Xcode, right? Use the Xcode organizer to view the crash log in a more readable form.

Comment: @MikeD Testing meant running it in the Simulator on my Macbook & also running it on my Iphone to test. Both of them didn't crash or return any errors. It only crashed once the update was downloaded to the device off the App store once approved

Comment: Now you are mentioning an update. Have you tested installing the new version over an old one?

Comment: Agree with rmaddy symbolicate the crash log is the way. But it is not a easy process as well.

Comment: @rmaddy Okay I just symbolicated the crash log. What am I looking for?

Comment: Look at the stack trace for thread 0. Find the highest reference to your own app and see what file and line is causing the problem. If needed, update your question by posted the stack trace for thread 0.

Comment: Your crash is coming from your AppDelegate.m, line 104. Looks like a problem with your core-data setup. To test this, delete your app from your device. Do a clean build in Xcode. Then build and debug your app. Most likely you haven't done the equivalent of a fresh install in some time.

Comment: @rmaddy The thing is, it isn't crashing before I upload the update to the App Store. Only once it is updated so basically I have to resubmit my binary for an update to test if it's working again :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the look of the log you probably have the default `Core Data` stack in your code, and in the update modified your object model. You then have problems with migration on an version update. There in the Core Data template there is a nice call to `abort()` in the

`- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator`

method. There is a nice long comment about how it shouldn't appear in production code and some ideas on migration. I'd take a look in that method and verify the `abort()` is gone.

Comment: Thank you so much! I removed the 'abort()' from the AppDelgate.m & I think my problem will be fixed. Only way to test it is to submit the update!

Comment: @user3364589 Before you submit, why not test on your own device? Using your customers as testers is a bad idea.

Comment: @user3364589 just removing the `abort()` does not fix the problem. you either need to migrate the changes or delete and rebuild the store. There are lots of resources on doing either of those. but the reason it hit the abort was because of problem, just removing that doesn't solve the problem, just the consequence.

Comment: @rmaddy I do test it on my device before submitting it, but it runs smooth on my device and crashes once uploaded to the store.

Comment: @user3364589 But are you replicating what the user does? Are you testing a fresh install and are you testing an update from the prior version of the app?